# How to pass Image from PictureBox to Crystal Report CROleObject Picture1?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have one picture box in windows form having picture in it.

now

i want to **show this picture to crystal report Picture Object**

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding the picture to a dataTable row and add this dataTable to the dataset containing my data and set this dataset as data source of report.

Suppose `im` is a variable of type `Image` and I defined a dataTable named `viewLabratory` in my `ReportsDataSet` dataset, code for adding it is omething like this:

```
    ReportsDataSet dsRep = new ReportsDataSet();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    im.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    ReportsDataSet.viewLabratoryRow dr = dsRep.viewLabratory.NewviewLabratoryRow();
    dr.armPic = ms.ToArray();
    dsRep.viewLabratory.AddviewLabratoryRow(dr);
```